# AJAX error is returned as Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

AJAX error is being returned as Success. How to return JSON error from ASP.NET MVC? Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Register(int EventID)
    {
        try
        {
            // code
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Thank you for registering!" });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
        }
    }


                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("Register", "Home")",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                    success: function(data) {
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                    }
                });
```

Comment: What do you mean by AJAX Error here? What's the response include?

Comment: Because your have caught the error on the server and are returning valid json (not the error). If you want the `error:` code to be hit, then do not catch the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `error` function gets executed only when the HTTP Response Code is not `HTTP 200 Ready`. You handle the error in the server-side and return proper response, which will be picked up by `success` function in the AJAX call. Instead, use the `status` variable in your JSON and handle it on the client side:

```
success: function(data) {
  if (typeof data == "string")
    data = JSON.parse(data);
  if (data.success) {
    // Code if success.
  } else {
    // Code if error.
  }
},
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (scroll down to the `error` section):

> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides `null`) are `"timeout"`, `"error"`, `"abort"`, and `"parsererror"`. When an HTTP error occurs, `errorThrown` receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."  **As of jQuery 1.5**, the `error` setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn.  **Note:** *This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.* This is an [Ajax Event](/Ajax_Events/).

Answer (score 2):

The Ajax **error method is hit only when** you get a **Yellow Screen Error** in the server side. In your scenario you are handling the error using try catch and returning a valid response. So this is not considered as a error but a valid response. **Remove your try catch** so that Ajax will pick up the error event, else if you want to show the actual error message from server then you can **use the `success` property to decide if the response was a success or a error** , its similar to what Praveen has already posted in his answer.

```
success: function(data) { 
  if (data.success) {  //as you are passing true/false from server side.
    // Code if success.
  } else {
    // Code if error.
  }
},
```